# Moduli space of quadrics over the projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am struggling to understand if the following is in general true. Consider a set of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ with complex coefficients.

$$
p_1 = a_1x^2 + a_2y^2 - a_3\\
p_2 = b_1 x^2 + b_2y^2 - b_3 \\
p_3 = c_1 x^2 + c_2y^2  \\
p_4 = d_1 x^2 + d_2y^2  \\
\vdots 
$$
For simplicity assume only 4 of those (note that except for the first two one, the rest have no constant terms). Then, is it true that a common zero exists for $p_1=0, p_2 = 0, p_3 = 0, p_4 = 0$?

Specifically:

Is the **moduli space** of such "simple" quadric polynomials (curves) **non empty**?

If so, is the **dimension known**?

And if not, **what is the way to approach this problem so as to determined if a common zero exists** (I do not care on finding it)**?**

---

For example the moduli space of conics over the projective plane is non-empty and is a projective space. However, I guess the quadrics above might have different moduli space (if any) given they have a constant term and they do not include linear terms.

Any reference or tip will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If $ p_1 = x^2 + y^2 - 1 $ and $ p_3 = x^2 + y^2 $, there can never be a common zero. As far as the question of having a common zero is concerned, all you have to do is look at the ideal generated by the $ p_i $. There is a common zero iff this ideal is not the unit ideal. I don't know what you mean by 'moduli space' here though. Moduli space of what?

Comment: Hi, you are right. I would like to find the relations among the coefficients $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2,d_1,d_2$ such that at least a solution exists. In that sense there might be a moduli of these parameters they live in such that a solution exists.

However, in my actual problem at hand, I am able to also determine the vector $(x \, y)$ as long as it is non-trivial (i.e., $(0\, 0)$.